# Expected argument of type "Entity", "Another Entity" given

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using a form (IngredienteType) with one EntityType field which have to show a list of items from a many to one relationship from the entity Grupo_ingrediente. 
It display the items correctly but when I send the form I have this error:

"Expected argument of type "ComponentesBundle\Entity\Ingrediente", "ComponentesBundle\Entity\Grupo_ingrediente" given";

Stack Trace: in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php at line 254

It's a very simple structure but I have that error with doctrine validation and I don't know why. In fact, I have have maked a lot of similar forms without problem. Any idea?

I'm using Symfony 2.8.23

Thanks

Form IngredienteType:

```
...
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ...
        ->add('grupoIngrediente', EntityType::class, array('class'=>'ComponentesBundle:Grupo_ingrediente', 'placeholder' => "", 'required'=>false))
        ...
        ;
    }   
...
```

Entity Ingrediente

```
...

class Ingrediente
{
...
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\ComponentesBundle\Entity\Grupo_ingrediente")
     */
    private $grupoIngrediente;

...
```

Entity Grupo_ingrediente

```
...
class Grupo_ingrediente
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="grupo_original", type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $grupoOriginal;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="grupo", type="string", length=100, unique=true)
     */
    private $grupo;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="activo", type="boolean")
     */
    private $activo;



/*********Getters and setters*****************/
   ....



    public function __toString(){
        return $this->grupo;
    }
}
```

Comment: might be argument getting passed to the setter method for that property. Can you update question to include what your setter is for `$grupoIngrediente`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that was the key, I had a stupid error in my setter